# Double/binary mutation

Tags: c++, binary

For the genetic algorithm that I am trying to create I implemented a mutation mechanism, but it's quite crude:

```
for (int j = 0; j < number_of_variables - 1; j++)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> mutation(0, 20);
    int mutation_outcome = mutation(rng);
        if (mutation_outcome == 1)
        {
            new_individuals[k].chromosomes[0].at(j) = dist(rng);
        }
}
```

What it effectively does is create a 1 in 20 chance of mutating one of the "genes" in my individual, the genes are all doubles.

It's working fine as it is, but what I really want to do is to be able to mutate the underlying bits.

For example, I have a gene with double value `-6.57885` which a converting website tells me is `0000000011000000000110100101000010111110000011011110110100101000` in bits.

Comment: Is not mutation all about is to pick a random "gene" and convert it to its opposite?

Comment: You really want to mutate the bits? With equal probabilities? No matter if they belong to the mantissa or the exponent? Why?

Comment: @FirstStep: Pick random genes - yes. Convert to opposite - not neccessarily. A gene is in general not a boolean value.

Comment: @FirstStep Yes, I would agree. It's just this was the best I could do so far, and it's better than nothing :) 

Frank Puffer: Yes, it seems like the most true-to-nature way to do it. Each gene can mutate, so being true-to-nature I see no way to do it different bit-wise. What makes you say that is not a good idea?

Comment: @Milan: Ok, but in nature the encoding is completely different from the encoding of a double number in a digital computer.

Comment: @frank but the structure will end up as a binary no? So why not we pick random positions in that "gene structure" and flip to opposite ( if 1 - > 0 and if 0 -> 1)

Comment: If you just want to use it as a binary sequence, it might be better to use long instead of double

Comment: @FrankPuffer Yes, definitely. I'd consider DNA base-4, binary base-2. Maybe as a later step I'll try and figure out how to represent that, actually. But I think we can agree binary is better than double, right?

Comment: @1.618, for the fitness calculation I use them as doubles, so ideally I could keep them as double and only change the underlying bit-value at the mutation part of the program.

Comment: Also, reason I haven't responded to/upvoted your answer yet is I'm still trying to figure out how to get that working. Just for the record :)

Comment: What do you want to happen if you turn the double into `NaN` by randomly flipping a bit?

Comment: @MarkB, I'd want it to be 0, I suppose. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 1):

To flip a random bit, start with 1, left shift it by a random number between 0 and 63, then XOR it with the double:

example that compiles, adjusted for the fact that you can't XOR a double, as Mark B pointed out:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

double mutate(double input)
{
    long double_as_long = *(long*)&input;
    int bit_index = rand() % 63;  //you must call srand(seed) somewhere first
    long mutator = 1 << bit_index;
    long output = double_as_long ^ mutator;
    return *(double*)&output;
}
```

You could call this a random number of times in a loop, depending on the degree of mutation desired.

I hope this helps.

EDIT:  I used `rand()` as an example to get the bit index, but I strongly encourage you to use a better random number generator.

Another edit:

**Bit operator explanation:**

Left Shift operator (`<<`) moves all the bits in a number to the left the specified number of times:

```
1 << 3
0001 becomes 1000
```

XOR operator, aka Exclusive OR, (`^`) "flips" bits where a 1 is set:

```
1001 ^ 0100 = 1101
0010 ^ 0011 = 0001
```

Comment: Is there a reason why this specific 0 to 63 range and this method XOR?

Comment: I'm not convinced that is going to do what you want, considering the *floating point* vars being used.

Comment: That depends on how you define "mutate" in this context.

Comment: @FirstStep; Because the `double` has 64 bits.

Comment: Actually, I was _assuming_ 64 bits, but it you wanted to be sure, you could use something like `sizeof(double) * 8`

Comment: You can't bit-xor a `double` in C++.

Comment: @MarkB I did not know that, although I guess it makes sense.  I edited the example to compensate for that.

Comment: I keep trying to figure it out, but it keeps displaying 5 (or whatever number I input as original double). This is how I'm using it: http://pastebin.com/7UZTPnuj. Am I doing something obvious wrong?

Comment: @Milan a few wrong things that I could see: 1. `output = 4` on line 16 was probably in there as a test that you forgot to take out.  2. you need to get the return value of the mutate function, since it does not modify the value in-place.  3. for better randomness, you should only create the RNG once, rather than each time the function is called.  I created a class to hold the RNG and the mutate function.  You can see the value changing in the debugger, but not in the print statement because of float precision.  Edited version here:  http://pastebin.com/Tu4WY4Zu

Comment: @1.618 You're right yes, that was indeed left over from testing. I set precision to 64 to display the entire sequence, but as far as I can see rather than changing the original test double (5, in this case) it changes the number entirely, since my output is `-92559592500555878920934457134753827644941087706852119959044096`. I really appreciate your help, but I don't see how this would work for the algorithm (or how I could change it so that it would, though that could very well be a lack of insight on my side).